# What is the best approach to get injected beans with same interface in factory using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I created one factory to decide what best implementation should be returned, based in some conditional check.

```
// Factory
@Component
public class StoreServiceFactory {

    @Autowired
    private List<StoreService> storeServices;

    public StoreService getService(){

        if(isActiveSale){
            return storeServices.get("PublicStoreService")
        }

        return storeServices.get("PrivateStoreService")
    }
}

//Service Implementations
@Service
@Qualifier("PublicStoreService")
public class PublicStoreService implements StoreService {

    public getStoreBalanceScore(){
        Do Stuff....
    }
}

@Service
@Qualifier("PrivateStoreService")
public class PrivateStoreService implements StoreService {

    public getStoreBalanceScore(){
        Do Stuff....
    }
}


    // Controller
    @Autowired
    StoreServiceFactory storeServiceFactory;

    @Override
    public StoreData getStoreBalance(String storeId) {
        StoreService storeService = storeServiceFactory.getService();
        return simulationService.simulate(sellerId, simulation);
    }
```

Is this approach good? If yes, how can i get my service from an elegant way?
   I would like to use only annotations, without configurations.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a map instead of a List and pass a string parameter to the getService method.

```
public class StoreServiceFactory {

    @Autowired
    private Map<String,StoreService> storeServices = new HashMap<>();

    public StoreService getService(String serviceName){

        if(some condition...){
            // want to return specific implementation on storeServices map, but using @Qualifier os something else
            storeServices.get(serviceName)
        }
    }
}
```

You can prepopulate the map with supported implementations. You can then get an appropriate service instance as follows :

```
    // Controller
    @Autowired
    StoreServiceFactory storeServiceFactory;

    @Override
    public StoreData getStoreBalance(String storeId) {
        StoreService storeService = storeServiceFactory.getService("private");//not sure but you could pass storeId as a parameter to getService
        return simulationService.simulate(sellerId, simulation);
    }
```

If you don't like using Strings, you can define an enum for the supported implementations and use that as the key for your map.

Comment: and how is this map filled? should the Map be
private Map<String,StoreService> storeServices = new HashMap<>(); instead?

Comment: My bad. Changed the Map. You can populate the map through spring itself.

Comment: just one thing.... i'ts a bad idea dont receive the parameter and decide inside the method? StoreService storeService = storeServiceFactory.getService(); and inside the method getService() make some validations and return the correct implementation? is this design bad? shoud this validation be done in my controller?

Comment: How are you going to validate inside the method?

Comment: @Mr.PaulHenry How will your method know which concrete implementation to use without being supplied some input? What logic will you use to do this?

Comment: @bot i will decide inside the method... is this a bad idea? should the controller make this decision?

Comment: @Mr.PaulHenry Your factory should only be responsible for creating objects. It should not know if a sale is active or not.. `isActiveSale` should not be an instance variable in your factory. Is the type of StoreService object to create only dependent on whether a sale is active or not?

Comment: @bot depending of this parameter that indicates that the store is on sale, we should return an specific service... i recently created an strategyFactory that decides what implementation must be returned...i would like to encapsulate this decision in one single place, to avoid programmer to know how the correct implementation... am i doing this wrong?

Comment: @minion i'm encapsulating this on factory to avoid have duplicated code to decide what implementation must be returned... the explanation is above..thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a list or map on your code. You can retrieve it directly from Spring context using **GenericBeanFactoryAccessor**. This has various method to retrieve a specific bean like based on name, annotation etc. You can take a look at javadoc here. This avoids unnecessary complexity.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/generic/GenericBeanFactoryAccessor.html